# How do I increment value from a row inserted with matching values?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-insert

So I am trying to do this process and want to avoid doing multiple db calls. I want to:

1. Insert values into database
2. After insert, increment a column 'count' based off similar values 'ticket_number'
3. And I want to use a trigger to automate it on insert

What I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ChatAutoIncrement
ON chat
FOR INSERT
BEGIN
    UPDATE chat
    SET
        count = ( ( SELECT u.cnt FROM ( SELECT ticket_id, count(*) as cnt FROM chat GROUP BY ticket_id ) u ) WHERE u.cnt > 1 )
    WHERE
        ticket_id IN
        (
            SELECT u.ticket_id, u.cnt
            FROM
                (
                SELECT ticket_id, count(*) as cnt
                FROM chat
                GROUP BY ticket_id
                ) u
            where u.cnt > 1
            GROUP BY u.ticket_id
        );
END;
```

This is what Workbench suggested:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `blil_insurance`.`ChatAutoIncrement` AFTER INSERT ON `chat` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE chat
    SET
        count =
        (
            SELECT u.cnt
            FROM
                (
                SELECT ticket_id, count(*) as cnt
                FROM chat
                GROUP BY ticket_id
                ) u
            where u.cnt > 1
            GROUP BY u.ticket_id
        )
    WHERE
        ticket_id IN
        (
            SELECT u.ticket_id, u.cnt
            FROM
                (
                SELECT ticket_id, count(*) as cnt
                FROM chat
                GROUP BY ticket_id
                ) u
            where u.cnt > 1
            GROUP BY u.ticket_id
        );
END
```

The table looks like this:

| count | ticket_id | date | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 22/01/2021 14:01:05 | 1 |
| 1 | 2534 | 22/01/2021 14:03:05 | 2 |
| 2 | 1234 | 22/01/2021 14:05:20 | 3 |
| 1 | 1234 | 22/01/2021 14:05:20 | 4 |

This is what I want it to look like after the third table is inserted:

| count | ticket_id | date | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 22/01/2021 14:01:05 | 1 |
| 1 | 2534 | 22/01/2021 14:03:05 | 2 |
| 2 | 1234 | 22/01/2021 14:05:20 | 3 |
| 3 | 1234 | 22/01/2021 14:08:20 | 4 |

I have tried:

- Checking syntax
- Doing it using MYSQL workbench (turned all numbers with the same 'ticket_id' to 3)
- Use a workaround that makes multiple database calls (will turn it very inefficient considering this is for a chat system)

----------------------------Edit---------------------------------------------

Added primary key 'id'

Comment: What's your primary key?, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry forgot to add it... sorry, it's just a column saying id that is auto incremented

Comment: @Strawberry added ID